# How to delete Cookie after page has changed Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

Im going to add cookie to specific page using javascript as simple as this

`document.cookie="username=John Doe";`

i want to make them expire when user change that specific page[Navigate to another page]. how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the cookie time to an expired date:

```
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

see: [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: no not like that is there anyway to delete them when user leave the page.

Comment: @CadeLewis Then just do it when the `onbeforeunload` event is raised. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload